# SearchCriteria with 'OR' filter

Tags: magento2, search-criteria

I would like to get Cms Pages from repository using search criteria.
I need to filter `title` and `content` fields.
This is how I'm trying to do this:

```
$this->filterBuilder->setField('title');
$this->filterBuilder->setValue('%keyword%');
$this->filterBuilder->setConditionType('like');
$filters[] = $this->filterBuilder->create();

$this->filterBuilder->setField('content');
$this->filterBuilder->setValue('%keyword%');
$this->filterBuilder->setConditionType('like');
$filters[] = $this->filterBuilder->create();

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($filters);
```

and it gives me following SQL:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `cms_page` AS `main_table` WHERE (`title` = '%keyword%') AND (`content` = '%keyword%')
```

while what I need is:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `cms_page` AS `main_table` WHERE (`title` = '%keyword%') OR (`content` = '%keyword%')
```

Comment: How have print this sql query? I am trying by :
echo (string) $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter($filter)->getSelect();
But getting error:  "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::getSelect()"

Answer (score 3):

You can try with,

```
$title = $this->filterBuilder->setField('title')
            ->setValue('%keyword%')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->create();

$content = $this->filterBuilder->setField('content')
            ->setValue('%keyword%')
            ->setConditionType('like')
            ->create();

$filterOr = $this->filterGroupBuilder
        ->addFilter($title)
        ->addFilter($content)
        ->create();

$searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterOr])->create();

$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($searchCriteria);
```

Comment: you can try comment out this line, 
//$this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilters($searchCriteria); and print $searchCriteria only.